# ¿Cómo comunicarme transitivamente entre componentes ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, component

Estoy con un tema de comunicación y actualización de componentes, el tema es que tengo una tabla(obtenerIndicaciones.js), que al querer agregar un registro abre un modal (nuevaIndicacionForm.js), una vez abierto el modal y llenado los campos, click en "agregar" y este botón llama a otro componente que es el post donde esta la lógica que conecta con la api(registrarIndicacion.js), ahora el tema es, cuando haga el post, necesito que si la respuesta es 200, actualice la tabla (obtenerIndicaciones.js).

Aquí subí la parte del proyecto donde necesito hacer esto. desde ya ¡muchas gracias! :) :
https://github.com/HoraciioMolina/help_UpdateState

Comment: Necesitas pasar al componente `ObtenerIndicaciones` que es quien tiene el estado de la lista de indicaciones la nueva indicación, para ello tienes que crear  en `ObtenerIndicaciones` un método que añada a la lista la indicación y para ellos tienes que pasar este método por props al componente que tiene esa lógica.

Comment: Mmm, me podrías dar un ejemplo de como quedaría? Es lo que vengo intentando hacer pero realmente, no me sale..

Comment: Para eso necesitaría ver la estructura del código, si puedes monta el proyecto en stackblitz

Comment: ahi esta el link de git, donde esta la parte donde necesito hacer esto, y con todos sus archivos, necesitas algo mas que eso?

Comment: He intentado ponerlo en marcha aquí pero se ve que me falta algo: [https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-gzk6rh?file=Get%2FobtenerIndicaciones.js](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-gzk6rh?file=Get%2FobtenerIndicaciones.js)

Comment: Es porque es una parte del proyecto.. necesitas el proyecto completo?

Comment: Si es posible completalo que falte aquí [https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-gzk6rh](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-gzk6rh)

Comment: Eso es porque faltan archivos necesarios para que renderize, dejame tu mail y te comparto el proyecto completo por github :)

Comment: vale, en github agrégame como `binomi0`

Comment: Listo, ya te invite..

Comment: Lo acabo de ver, voy a descargarlo

Comment: me pide usuario y contraseña, deberiamos seguir por un chat

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/horacioo.molina este es mi facebook.. seguimos por ahi si te parece :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Añade un método a la clase `obteberIndicaciones`

```js
ActualizarComponenteTabla = () => {
    this.loadIndicaciones()
  }
```

Y ahora pásaselo al hijo por props:

```js
  <div className="btn-nuevo">
    <NuevaIndicacionForm
      ActualizarComponenteTabla={this.ActualizarComponenteTabla}
    />
  </div>
```

y ya solo te queda llamar a ese método cuando el usuario añada la indicación

```js
postNuevaIndicacion() {
  this.setState({isLoading : true})
  registrarIndicacion(this.state).then(
     resolve => {
        this.props.ActualizarComponenteTabla()
        alert("La indicacion se creo con exito")
        this.setState({...this.state, show: false , number: this.state.number + 1, isLoading: false});
      },
      reject => {
        alert("No se pudo crear la indicacion")
        this.setState({isLoading: false});
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: Esto soluciono mi problema, Muchas gracias!